# How do I hide the underlying text of a div without background color?

Tags: css, html, background, stylesheet

I'm trying to overlay two `div` elements, the underlying has a background the overlaying can not have one, since later there will be a background image in the back.
I want the underlying text to be cut off at the place where it is behind the overlaying `div`.
The only way I found was to set `background-color: white;` to the overlaying `div`, as mentioned this is not possible.
Any tip/solution how do I accomplish this?

```
<div style="background-color:red;z-index:1;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;left:262px;top:222px;width:191px;height:48px;">
This is a TEST text.
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid black;z-index:2;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;left:152px;top:177px;width:199px;height:156px;">
Top Element
</div>
```

[image: overlaying divs]

Comment: Set background-color, then _later_, just before bg image is rendered, set bg color back to transparent.

Comment: What if you make the overlaying background have the same background colour as the underlaying one?

Comment: i guess its not pissible without using plain (and same) colors or different techniques like float, width and so on.

Comment: uh can you draw  a picture or something of what you want the first and second stages to look like? Or just describe it more?

Comment: In general, the snipped above is a simplyfied version of the actuall content, there are many documents which content is generated having lots of divs, some overlaying some not.

Comment: So I hoped to have a simple css attribute trick that does the job, I would prefere not to use JavaScript.
@2unco, since the content is generated I don't have control of the colors

Comment: @Abernasty I actually had a PrintScreen ready, but I had not enough reputation to post images

Comment: "cut off at the place where it is behind the overlaying div" is extremely vague, can you link to anywhere that shows something like you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? Basically, I've added a third div with the background color white that you can set it's display to none when the image goes into the lower div. This is mainly just a thought, it can probably be applied to the lower div instead.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #botDiv{
            background-color:red;
            z-index:1;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:absolute;
            left:262px;
            top:222px;
            width:191px;
            height:48px;
        }
        #topDiv{
            border:1px solid black;
            z-index:2;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:absolute;
            left:152px;
            top:177px;
            width:199px;
            height:156px;
        }
        #interSectingDiv{
            background-color:#fff;
            position:relative;
            top:26px;
            left:109px;
            overflow:hidden;
            width:191px;
            height:48px;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="botDiv">
This is a TEST text.
</div>
<div id="topDiv">
Top Element
    <div id="interSectingDiv"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[ updated ]
Another thought, is that you can probably shorten the width of the lower div by the amount of space it consumes from the higher div and position it at the right edge of the higher div until the image goes in (you'll most likely have to use animation in your css that's triggered by some form of javascript).

Comment: As stated in the comment above: "In general, the snipped above is a simplyfied version of the actuall content, there are many documents which content is generated having lots of divs, some overlaying some not.. So I hoped to have a simple css attribute trick that does the job"

For all the differnt divs your approach will probably be too complicated, thanks anyway though.